# Unity android application doesn't quit

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, keyboard-events

I create an android application by generate `.apk` using unity3d-vuforia. When I click `back` button, the app doesn't quit. I handle press back button.

I edit `customEventHandler.cs` file that is created by unity.
My code is here :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class customEventHandler : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Application.Quit();
        // or ask to quit
    }
}
}
```

I don't sure whethet I can add it. I have a 2d marker and a virtual car. The car is 3d object. I check event handler, my screenshot is below :

[image]

**EDIT**

I solve the problem using below code. I don't delete this post because matbe the solution hepls someone. I edited `ImageTargetBehaviour.cs` file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 /// <summary>
 /// This class serves both as an augmentation definition for an ImageTarget  in the editor
/// as well as a tracked image target result at runtime
/// </summary>
 public class ImageTargetBehaviour : ImageTargetAbstractBehaviour
 {
 void OnGUI () {

    // call this block
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Application.Quit();
        // or ask to quit
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.), something should come after the . (dot). Also have you attached the customEventHandler to any gameobject in the scene? You can attach it for example to the camera object.

Comment: I edited my question text.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/369198/how-to-exit-application-in-android-on-back-button.html

Comment: I had tried your solution before I wrote this question, but it had not worked for me.

Comment: you must add this script inside of your main camera hope it help you.